# How to delete users from database?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I make test in Laravel, and I want to truncate all users, and create only one. This code show me error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint`. What can I do that truncate users ?  Just I don't want to use solutions that violate database settings, e.g.`Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();`

```
 public function test_delete_user()
    {
 
        DB::table('users')->truncate();
        $role = User::factory()->create();
     .......
        
    }
```

Comment: You would have to remove those records in which those users are set as value for the foreign key, first.

Comment: Would [Resetting The Database After Each Test](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) help?

Comment: Before tuncating user tabel you muset need to delete relational records or trunctare table that user Foreign Key of user table

Comment: @SagarSainkar How can I delete relational records ?

Comment: As in your example code you are not using models then you have to use same query for all Foreign Key tables from user table before truncating user table
 
 DB::table('table_name')->truncate();  @perh22

Answer (score -1):

Your table user have a forign key constraint remove that to get truncate working.

Can i see the database schema.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name;
```

This is for MysQl try that on your table

Comment: Or try to find how to do that on the type of your database

Answer (score -1):

Before using

```
DB::table('users')->truncate();
```

You may try to use (suppose your foreign table name "addresses")

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE addresses DROP FOREIGN KEY addresses_user_id_foreign');
```

It may help you.
Then it may look like

```
public function test_delete_user()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE addresses DROP FOREIGN KEY addresses_user_id_foreign');
 
        DB::table('users')->truncate();
        $role = User::factory()->create();
     .......
        
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want to use solutions that violate database settings, then 
- at first, you may update other table foreign_key_id value to 1
- export the table with data
- delete all data from the table
- then you may delete all data from user table
- now you may create your first data by id 1 (which will use as foreign key by other table)
- now you may import exported data to your other table.
I think it will work, because it worked for me.